# cordova cannot see Android target

Tags: cordova, sdk

I tried to setup Ionic+Cordova for the Android platform. I installed JDK, Android SDK etc. but running `cordova requirements` gives me:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<initSchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<initSchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinitAndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
        ... 5 more
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\bin\gradle
```

Comment: did you already solve the problem?
i have same problem now.

Comment: Any updates on this? I have same issue on java 13.0.1 version?

Answer (score 5):

This means that the emulator your are trying to run your app in is not running. You need to install or run this emulator. Try running the emulator first, for example on my end it looks like this:
[image: Shows the green "PLAY" button if your setup is correct]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It helped to solve my problem! I didn't turn on the emulator while executing command to run server on emulator.

Comment: This is weird. I thought that the command cordova run android will automatically open the emulator as well. so you have to manually open the emulator first before executing this command.

Answer (score 2):

Check your JDK version?
I used JDK9 that was making the same error. After installation JDK 8 error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your JDK version. Cordova upto version 9 only support java 8, in version 10 you can use java 11
You can download previous version by login oracle.com and searching the version 8 JDK. Once you install JDK then set the system variable in 'User' as JAVA_HOME and path of your JDK.
also set for ANDROID_HOME by following this [guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html).

Some times , Environment variables need PC reboot to take effect.

Now go to go to the app folder and check cordova requirements. Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

These answers are outdated. The current version of Cordova uses JDK 11. I had this error on my windows 11 laptop and it took me a while to track it down. In the Windows environment variables, check the Path values in both:

- User variables and..
- System variables

I found that I had multiple JDK path values in the System "Path" variable that were causing problems. I deleted all of them except the correct JDK path and it fixed the issue.
More details here:
https://wastedpotential.com/fix-for-cordova-error-android-target-not-installed-cmd-command-failed-with-exit-code-1/

Answer (score 0):

Change your "jdk any version"  to "1.8.any version". In short Cordova requires you to have jdk 1.8 installed.

Answer (score 0):

try to Install the [Android SDK Command-line Tools]
[image]